# Solve integral $\int \frac{1-(1+cx)e^{-cx}}{cx^2}dx$

Tags: integration, analysis

If I plug $$\int \frac{1-(1+cx)e^{-cx}}{cx^2}dx$$ into WolframAlpha I get $$\frac{e^{-cx}-1}{cx}+\text{constant}$$
as the result. If I derive the later one I see that this is correct, but how do I solve the integral by hand to obtian the claimed result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have, $$I=\int \frac{1-(1+cx)e^{-cx}}{cx^2} dx =\frac{1}{c} \int \frac{1}{x^2} dx -\frac{1}{c} \int (\frac{ce^{-cx}}{x} +\frac{e^{-cx}}{x^2}) dx =\frac{1}{c}[I_1-I_2]$$

Now, $I_1$ is very easy to compute, let us calculate $I_2$. Integrating by parts, we have, $$I_2= -\int \frac{ce^{-cx}}{x} dx + \int \frac{ce^{-cx}}{x} dx -\frac{e^{-cx}}{x} = -\frac{e^{-cx}}{x}$$

Hope you can complete it from here.

Comment: Can you clarify the calculation of $I_2$? What is the $u$, what is the $v'$?

Comment: @3456dg In $I_2$, first calculating $\int \frac{e^{-cx}}{x^2} dx$, we take $u=e^{-cx}$ and $v’=\frac{1}{x^2}$.

Answer (score 0):

Setting $$t=1+cx$$ then we get
$$dt=cdx$$ and $$x=\frac{t-1}{c}$$

Comment: Okay then I get $\int \frac{1-te^{1-t}}{(t-1)^2} dt$. This seems better but still I have no clue how to solve this.

Comment: then you can Substitute $$u=t-1$$

Comment: Okay then we are at $\int \frac{1-(u+1)e^{-u}}{u^2} du$. Why is this closer to the result?

Comment: then you can split the integral

Comment: write $$\frac{1}{u^2}-\left(\frac{1}{u}+\frac{1}{u^2}\right)e^{-u}$$

Comment: Okay, so: $\int \frac{1}{u^2} du - \int \left( \frac{1}{u} + \frac{1}{u^2} \right) e^{-u} du$ The first one is $-1/u$. But why is the 2nd one $-\frac{e^{-u}}{u}$?

Comment: it is $$\frac{e^{-u}}{u}-\frac{1}{u}+C$$